Google Vision API TEXT_DETECTION textAnnotation is empty
I'm using Google Vision API TEXT_DETECTION (with Java)
I got response successful. It's successful only fullTextAnnotation.
and textAnnotation is empty.. I don't know why
I used Vision API REST with retrofit2.
below is the response json:
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "fullTextAnnotation": {
                //successful
            },
            "textAnnotations": [
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

and this is java model code:
//Root class
//...

class Response {
    @SerializedName("textAnnotations")
    List<TextAnnotations> textAnnotations;
    @SerializedName("fullTextAnnotation")
    FullTextAnnotation fullTextAnnotation;
}

class TextAnnotations {
    InTextAnnotationWithLocale inTextAnnotationWithLocale;
    List<InTextAnnotation> inTextAnnotations;
}

class InTextAnnotationWithLocale {
    @SerializedName("locale")
    String locale;
    @SerializedName("description")
    String description;
    @SerializedName("boundingPoly")
    BoundingPoly boundingPoly;
}

class InTextAnnotation {
    @SerializedName("description")
    String description;
    @SerializedName("boundingPoly")
    BoundingPoly boundingPoly;
}

class BoundingPoly {
    @SerializedName("vertices")
    List<Vertex> vertices;
}

class Vertex {
    @SerializedName("x")
    int x;
    @SerializedName("y")
    int y;
}

//fullTextAnnotation
//...

I search vision api document, but I couldn't find solution.

this site requires a question-answer format. do not put your solution into your question. post it as an answer.

I found a solution. The cause was the Model code.. I changed like below
class Response {
    @SerializedName("textAnnotations")
    List<TextAnnotation> textAnnotations;
    @SerializedName("fullTextAnnotation")
    FullTextAnnotation fullTextAnnotation;
}

class TextAnnotation {
    @SerializedName("locale")
    String locale;
    @SerializedName("description")
    String description;
    @SerializedName("boundingPoly")
    BoundingPoly boundingPoly;
}

It was a simple problem and it's was my mistake
